# Android KenBurnEffect Issue

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-image, android-kenburnsview

I have an issue related to [KenBurnsEffect](https://github.com/gotokatsuya/KenBurnsView) library.

In this library they set an images from remote URL..
like this..

```
 public static final String[] IMAGES20 = new String[] {

            "http://simpozia.com/pages/images/stories/windows-icon.png",
            "http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/radio.png",
            "http://www.bandwidthblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/twitter-logo.png",
            "http://weloveicons.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/100907_itunes1.png"
};

 List<String> urls = Arrays.asList(IMAGES20);

 final KenBurnsView kenBurnsView = (KenBurnsView)findViewById(R.id.ken_burns_view);

 kenBurnsView.initUrls(urls);
```

This works perfectly.

**But in my project, i need to set images from `drawable` folder..**

To reference a drawable as URL string, i have used `drawable://" + R.drawable.img_splash_1,`

Implementation is like this...

```
     List<String> IMAGES20= Arrays.asList(

               "drawable://" + R.drawable.img_splash_1,
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.img_splash_2,
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.img_splash_3,
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.img_splash_4,
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.img_splash_5,
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.img_splash_6,
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.img_splash_7

             );


   List<String> urls = Arrays.asList(IMAGES20);

   final KenBurnsView kenBurnsView = (KenBurnsView)findViewById(R.id.ken_burns_view);

   kenBurnsView.initUrls(urls);
```

But this does not work.. It shows a blank screen. No Exceptions nothing.
I can't understand what is the issue...

Please help me..

Comment: Even i know that there are thousands of way to do that.. but my question is related to KenburnsView library. they are using some Glide Image Loader library. and i am not sure how to load local image through that library.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library, It may be helpful:

https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve ?

I think you should write like below.

```
List<Integer> resourceIDs = Arrays.asList(...);
kenBurnsView.initResourceIDs(resourceIDs);
```